# Broken UI on Safari

Tags: bug, user-interface, safari

I tried to open Stack Overflow in Safari today. As result I can't see the UI. Safari version 13.0.3 (14608.3.10.10.1) and macOS v10.14 (Mojave).

> [image: Failed to load resource: an ssl error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. Reference error: Cant find variable: StackExchange]
>
> [image: UI]

Comment: Are you behind a (shool / work / country's) firewall?

Comment: You need to allow traffic from `cdn.sstatic.net`. If you paste this in your address bar of your browser `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js` what do you get? if it isn't javascript then that is your problem.

Comment: @rene I don't know what went on but I can open stackoverflow from Chrome and it's looks good

Comment: Huh? That is super weird. Got security tightened in Safari 13? That seems unlikely to happen but you never know ... Glad you got one browser working!

Comment: Sigh. Please include text as text, [not pictures of text](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: @HereticMonkey: What picture in here should've been text? There is no code here. Just some error messages that really aren't better off when copy-pasted to a poorly formattable code block.

Comment: @Cerbrus at least when error messages are in text, quote block or code block, they can be searched for. Nothing in this question body now links to any technical details that can be looked up by others.

Comment: They're pretty common error messages that get a lot of results not related to SO, though. Unless you explicitly search on meta SO... I've added the errors to the image's description. That should help.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you for adding the errors to the images description. That should help visually impaired people understand what the errors are too...

Comment: No problem, @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely not a bug but a localised issue.

I'm using same Safari version, 13.0.3; everything just load fine (browser details below);

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Safari/605.1.15
```

Can you confirm use of any extension? If Yes, review settings.

Otherwise, you may be experiencing this due to a firewall restriction on your network.